# Visual Source Safe on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, visual-sourcesafe

Is there an application or API for using/accessing Visual SourceSafe (6.0) under Mac OS X? I'm currently using VSS Connect under Parallels for working with our company's ASP.NET site/s. I currently have my Windows drive shared and try to use TextMate on the Mac side to actually edit files. It would be nice to have the ability to check files in/out outside of my virtual machine though.

Comment: Your current solution to use a native Windows client within a VM is pretty much what our team has arrived at for the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility would be to use the X Windows version of Source OffSite.  See discussion [here](http://aricsblog.blogspot.com/2006/04/sourceoffsite-for-mac-os-x.html).  There does not seem to be an official OS X client for VSS, however.

That same link also discusses DynamSoft's [Source Anywhere](http://www.dynamsoft.com/Products/SAW_Overview.aspx), which is a cross-platform solution written in Java.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

Considering SourceSafe sucks on Windows, trying to use a client for it on a MAC is probably very ill advised.

Everyone who still uses SourceSafe should [read this](http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/windev/sourcesafe.html). If you can't move to something better due to reasons beyond your control then I feel sorry for you!

Comment: I use SourceSafe for the last 10 years with teams from 1 to 20 users , with NO problems so far.

Comment: @anon2009- that's good, but you were probably just lucky. The issues with SourceSafe are well documented. Here's a nice article from Coding Horror- http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000660.html

Comment: While I agree that VSS sucks and that ideally nobody would ever _want_ or _need_ to use it on OS X, the fact is that this is not really an answer to the question.

Comment: @sholsinger- but it gets the original poster thinking about using alternatives, which can only be a good thing.

Comment: I actually don't have to worry about this anymore but before it didn't matter if I thought about alternatives or not, the decision to use VSS was not an option. The company used it therefore I had to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Metroworks used to maintain a copy of visual sourcesafe for OS 9.

I tried and was able to succesfully run it on OS X.

You can find a download here: http://download.cnet.com/Metrowerks-Visual-SourceSafe/3000-2247_4-2881.html

Comment: Hi , chollida i actually need this software ,and the link provided by you is not working any more and it is also not available in net.So can you please deposit the software somewhere and provide the link.

Comment: @raaz the link works for me. It completed a download.  I'm on a windows box right now so I couldn't use it.  What is the problem you are encountering?

Comment: Hi,chollida sorry to disturb you again.
When i open the link and press the "Download Now" option .It shows Thank you for downloading Metrowerks Visual SourceSafe
Your download will begin in a moment and it opens a link ftp://ftp.metrowerks.com/pub/updates/MWVSS6/MW_VSS_6.0.1_Update.hqx
and it take too much time to open and finally shows a message :The connection has timed out The server at ftp.metrowerks.com is taking too long to respond.
And when i tried to open the publisher site http://www.metrowerks.com/ it opens http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/homepage.jsp?nodeId=012726

Comment: @raaz, bummer.  I'm sorry if the link doesn't work for you then there isn't really anything I can do to help you.

I would try contacting Metrowerks directly.

Answer (score 1):

Ops! What you're really looking for is for a replacement for your good-ol TFS. If you need to work on Mac OS X too I'd recommend:

- Perforce: www.perforce.com -> very strong, very fast and used by a huge amount of companies out there
- Plastic SCM: www.plasticscm.com -> extremely good for branching and merging (if you don't do it now is because VSS can't) and distributed. It's newer than Perforce so you'll only jump into it if you're really an early adopter.